# C# compiler error with explicit type vars sent to method with ref objects (converting from VB.net)

Tags: c#, vb.net, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Long time programmer, new to C#.  I am in the process of converting a solution from VB.net to C#.  This particular function "getdata" returns values from the first row in a sql select.  For this example I've simplified the code.

Due to the unknown datatypes being fetched from sql, the "getdata()" parms are objects.  VB allows calling a function with any explicit datatype byref parms into objects, so I can send a string or int parm into an object and return it with no issues.

In C#, this method works for passing parms by value.  Any type of byref (ref/in/out) the compiler arrors with "cannot convert from ref string to ref object"

What I've tried:

- Changing all manner of parm ref/var type (in/out/ref/nothing)
- Changing datatypes of variables from explicit to object works but produces lots of issues downstream.  ie. I don't want to define everything as an object/I much prefer explicit datatypes.
- explicit cast before calling using (object) before the variable name.
- Changing everything to Dynamic types works but same issues as object.

My best solution, unfortunately, changes the functionality enough that it's going to cause issues with further solution conversion. I came up with returning the a/b/c variables as an anonymous object that are that set to the actual variables upon return to the calling function.

Is there any way that calling function parms can be explicitly typed and passed to an implicit data type like object?
If not, any better solution than returning anonymous type?

VB code -- working

```
    Private Sub test() 

        Dim a$, b%, c$
        getdata(1, a, b, c)
        MsgBox($"a={a}, b={b}, c={c}")

        Dim x As DateTime, y As String, z As String
        getdata(2, x, y, z)
        MsgBox($"x={x}, y={y}, z={z}")

    End Sub



    Private Sub getdata(opt As Integer, ByRef val0 As Object, ByRef Optional val1 As Object = Nothing, ByRef Optional val2 As Object = Nothing) As Boolean

       'the real implementation of this function will accept sql string and return first row of data columns
       'since fetched data will be of different types, parms are defined as objects

        If opt = 1 Then
            val0 = "Apples"
            val1 = 2
            val2 = "Oranges"
        ElseIf opt = 2 Then
            val0 = now
            val1 = "Dogs"
            val2 = "Cats"
        End If

    End Function
```

C# code -- compiler error -
I am hand converting VB code to help with the C# learning curve but my last ditch solution was to use a VB->C# converter which is produced here.

```
    private void test()
        {

            string a = null;
            int b = 0;
            string c = null;
            getdata(1, ref a, ref b, ref c);            ************** error occurs here
            MessageBox.Show($"a={a}, b={b}, c={c}");        "cannot convert from ref string to ref object"

            DateTime x = default(DateTime);
            string y = null;
            string z = null;
            getdata(2, ref x, ref y, ref z);            ************** error occurs here
            MessageBox.Show($"x={x}, y={y}, z={z}");        "cannot convert from ref string to ref object"

        }

        private bool getdata(int opt, ref object val0, ref object val1, ref object val2)
        {
            //real function will accept sql string and return first row of data columns
            //since fetched data will be of different types, parms are defined as objects
            if (opt == 1)
            {
                val0 = "Apples";
                val1 = 2;
                val2 = "Oranges";
            }
            else if (opt == 2)
            {
                val0 = DateTime.Now;
                val1 = "Dogs";
                val2 = "Cats";
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: You need x.ToString(), y.ToString(), z.ToString()

Comment: @jdweng: The primary errors occur in the calls to getdata.

Comment: If the return results are always interpolated into a string like the example `MessageBox.Show`, then the arguments could be changed from `object` to `string`. In order to achieve that the assignment would always need to convert the values to strings.

Comment: If the data types are known at compile time, and they will always be the same for the given call, the method could be converted to a generic method, i.e., `bool get data<T0, T1, T2>(int opt, ref T0 val0, ref T1 val1, ref T2 val2)`.

Comment: what is the point of `out object` if the variable declared `int b = 0;`??

Comment: Faced with your situation here, I would be doing something along the lines of reworking the GetDates() to accept and return a dictionary or looking at what I'm actually sending that function, can it be simplified to work with just strings, then do type casts before and after calling

Comment: The data types are not necessarily known at compile time.  getData() is used by many different calls with many different parameter types but generic method looks promising, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @wilson: You'll hit a dead end pretty quickly with generics on this problem - val0 = "Apples" - this won't work.

Comment: It definitely sounds like the original code gave up too soon on preserving type safety. This sometimes happen in VB.Net projects, where you can just have a file in the project with `Option Strict Off` for a module or two. In a C# project, you will reap large benefits from re-examining things to find a way to preserve type safety and not allowing `object` arguments. For example, you might just allow the method to return a `DataRow` object, rather than individual variables for each column.

Comment: Also, if you have a function like this that accepts SQL strings, there **MUST** also be a mechanism for accepting input parameter values. Otherwise, you're forcing yourself to build the SQL in ways that are crazy-vulnerable to SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 2):

There are some fundamental things in this method which make me believe you should spend more time refactoring vs direct translation. Restoring type safety is one of them (VB.Net made it easier to hide some poor type safety choices in a file where you have `Option Strict Off` for a couple modules), but this also **REALLY** scares me:

---

> *//real function will accept sql string*

---

Functions like that tend to cause **HUGE** security problems, as well as other issues, especially when you also have a bunch of arguments for output values. If you're not well-versed in SQL Injection, *NOW* is the time to learn about it. You **must** also provide a way to include input data for the SQL command that is completely separate from the SQL string itself, or you'll eventually find yourself in big trouble.

*This code needs some serious refactoring, not just simple conversion!*

I suggest refactoring around a method like this:

```cs
public class DB
{
    private static string ConnectionString {get;} = "connection string here";

    private static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> getdata(string sql, Action<SqlParameterCollection> addParameters)
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            addParameters(cmd.Parameters);

            cn.Open();
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                    yield return rdr;
                rdr.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the method is **private**; this is because we're not done building the class yet. Once you create this class, and remove the old `getdata()` method, *everywhere* that currently calls this method will turn into a compiler error. This is good; it gives you an easy way to find all those places you had poor code of this type.

So now we start looking at the new compiler errors. Each one will represent a place where you used to call `getdata()`. There's probably other code nearby to build up the SQL string. You want to move each of these sections to a new static method in the `DB` class.

One of those methods might look something like this:

```cs
public static IDataRecord MyNewDataMethod(int ID)
{
    string SQL = "SELECT ... WHERE ID = @ID";

    return getdata(SQL, p => {
        p.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
    }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But we can (and should) take this a step further. Typically, these results will represent objects of some type. After all, they had to come from a table, or at least a set of related tables. If you don't already have a **class** for each of these things, you probably should. These classes should have static methods named something like `FromDataRecord()`, which accept an IDataRecord or DataRow as input and return the class type as output. They are Factory methods. And now we update the methods to look more like this:

```
public static MyObjectType MyNewDataMethod(int MyObjectTypeID)
{
    string SQL = "SELECT ... WHERE ID = @ID";

    return getdata(SQL, p => {
        p.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MyObjectTypeID;
    }).Select(MyObjectType.FromDataRecord).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Here's another example that might return several records:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyObjectType> MyNewDataMethod(string SearchKey)
{
    string SQL = "SELECT ... WHERE SearchColumn = @SearchKey + '%'";

    return getdata(SQL, p => {
        p.Add("@SearchKey", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 80).Value = SearchKey;
    }).Select(MyObjectType.FromDataRecord);
}
```

If you find you have a *lot* of these methods, you can convert the private `getdata()` method to **protected**, put it in it's own class library project in the solution, and use separate public classes in the same project that can still access that method to divide the data access into logical areas.

Comment: I think I'd refactor it to use Dapper rather than reimplement Dapper..

Comment: We know we have sql injection issues.  This project was originally developed in vb3 many moons ago.  Resources are an issue but we do have an overload for parameterized query rather than straight sql.

Comment: **NOW** is the time to close that issue up for good. The only place you accept an SQL string is a **private** class method. Code that builds these strings must be moved to become members of this class; limit this to the least amount of code possible. Data needed to complete the strings become strongly-typed input arguments for the method. Results are return values. It makes it easy to audit the methods are handling SQL in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Joel's sentiments; throw this code away rather than trying to salvage it. It's garbage.

If you add a reference to the Nuget package Dapper, your life will get a lot easier. With Dapper, you write SQL and it maps to objects for you. It looks something like this:

```
using(var c = new SqlConnection(connection_string_here){

   var person = c.QueryFirst<(string Na, string Ad, int Ag)>("SELECT name, address, age FORM person WHERE id = @id", new { id = 123 });

}
```

There's a lot going on in this, so i'll unpack it:

- The first line just creates a database conenction in a using, so it will be disposed of. You don't need to bother about anything else; Dapper will open the connection, use it, close it
- The second line has some parts:
- `var person =`  - like `Dim x = 1` in VB, `var` declares a variable that is type-detected by the compiler from whatever type is on the right hand side
- `c.QueryFirst<(string Na, string Ad, int Ag)>` - QueryFirst is a Dapper extension method that runs a select query and pulls the first row. Dapper maps the query columns to the type you give in angle brackets. Here I've given a ValueTuple which is a way to get the C# compiler to "fake" a class for you based on the ValueTuple class. A discussion about how it works is a bit out of scope, but suffice to say when the compiler encounters `(string X, string Y, int Z)` it transforms behind the scenes into something that you can refer to as an object with those named/typed properties. Suffice to say, when all is done, you'll be able to say `person.Na` or `person.Ad` in your code
- `"SELECT name, address, age FORM person WHERE id = @id"` - is a parameterized SQL. It looks up a person with some ID and pulls their data out in that order, name, address, age. The order in this case is important because AFIAWA dapper maps ValueTuples positionally, not by name. This is different to other things (example later) where it does map by name. The tuple has name/address/age, so the query pulls them in the same order
- `new { id = 123 }`  - is creating a C# anonymous type, a sort of internal-only compiler generated class (different to a valuetuple) that has no name, but does have a property called `id` with value 123. Dapper will scan your SQL string looking for parameters, and find one called `@id`, so it will pull the value `123` out of the supplied anonymous type's `id` property (name based this time, not positional)

If you have a class Person lying around, as you probably *should* if you're doing any reasonable amount of database-to-c#-and-back-again work, then the call can look like this:

```
class Person{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}

...

    c.QueryFirst<Person>("SELECT age, name, address FROM ... WHERE id = @i", new { i=123 });
```

This time we pass a full class Person - Dapper will map the proeprties by name, which is why they're in a different order in the SQL (it could even be `SELECT *` and dapper will just ignore the 10+ columns in our person table that arent represented by an class property) and it still works. If your SQL names don't match your class names, the simplest thing to do is alias them in the SQL:

```
c.QueryFirst<Person>("SELECT firstname+' '+lastname as name, ... FROM ... WHERE id = @i", new { i=123 });
```

Comment: Dapper is nice and all. I actually quite like it (upvote). But it's still extra allocations for the input parameter mapping, and still needs reflection (slower) for mapping back the return data. It's also still a good practice to put code which uses in its own separate area (either class for small programs, namespace for medium, or class library for big). So really, we haven't gained all that much over the new getdata() method in my answer.

Comment: Can't be too shabby if it runs StackOverflow though right? :)

Comment: http://dapper-tutorial.net has a load of good stuff on, and posting questions about it here usually sees input from one of the authors, Marc Gravell

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an elegant solution - you can keep your 'getdata' method unchanged if you add extra baggage to every method call:

```
private void test()
{
    string a = null;
    int b = 0;
    string c = null;

    object temp_a = a;
    object temp_b = b;
    object temp_c = c;
    getdata(1, ref temp_a, ref temp_b, ref temp_c);
    a = (string)temp_a;
    b = (int)temp_b;
    c = (string)temp_c;

    MessageBox.Show($"a={a}, b={b}, c={c}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following

---

```
Hashtable gd = getData();

string location = (string)gd["location"];
int locationid = (int)gd["locationid"];
string frutata = (string)gd["frutata"];
```

where getData() just builds a hashtable of objects with the datareader columns.

---

My end goal was to create a simple callable function w/o a bunch of code to handle return values.

Dapper seems pretty cool and I will def. check that out.